# Unsure whether to use a Trigger or Procedure in SQL project

Tags: mysql

This is my example relation that I am working with named 'Balance Sheet' with 4 attributes.

```
        Balance Sheet

| companyTicker | assets | liabilities | equity |
```

If someone adds a tuple to this relation where `(assets != liabilities + equity)`  I would like either an error to be thrown saying that the data is invalid, or for the tuple to simply not be added. Should i use a procedure or something like a "before Update" trigger for this?

Comment: If you use a procedure, it won't help if someone updates the table directly instead of going through your procedure. A trigger will run for any update.

Comment: Why do you need an `assets` column if it's always `liabilities + equity`?

Comment: That's application-level validation, not database level. Why is `assets` even necessary? Are you sorting on that? Can't you compute it on-demand?

Comment: True, I could probably just compute it on demand. I didnt think of that. but I will definitely need 'assets' later on because i will be creating tables that use that attribute for various calculations i.e. 'returnOnAssets'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this answer [SQL Differences between stored procedure and triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628484/sql-differences-between-stored-procedure-and-triggers)
by @Bohemian. Since the check is to be performed at the time of insertion or when updating, go with triggers.