# Execute TRUNCATE in a trigger after a previous trigger fully completes

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm having an issue with trying to get a second trigger to execute after the first trigger fully completes.  The first trigger is executing based on an AFTER INSERT on a table.  The second trigger I just want to run after the first trigger, since the second trigger is just a truncate statement deleting the data from the tables that previously got inserted new rows.

Here's the code and error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_vppasubmission_trigger_function()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO contact("contact_id", "submission_date", "first_name", "last_name", "street_address", "street_address_2", "city", "state",
                    "zip", "county", "phone_number", "email", "dob", "facebook_exists", "facebook_year", "facebook_email", 
                    "facebook_phone_number")
SELECT "contact_id", "submission_date", "first_name", "last_name", "street_address", "street_address_2", "city", "state",
        "zip", "county", "phone_number", "email", "dob", "facebook_exists", "facebook_year", "facebook_email", "facebook_phone_number"
FROM "VPPA_HOLDING"
ON CONFLICT("email") DO UPDATE SET "submission_date" = EXCLUDED.submission_date, "first_name" = EXCLUDED.first_name,
                                "last_name" = EXCLUDED.last_name, "street_address" = EXCLUDED.street_address, "street_address_2" = EXCLUDED.street_address_2,
                                "city" = EXCLUDED.city, "state" = EXCLUDED.state, "zip" = EXCLUDED.zip, "county" = EXCLUDED.county, "phone_number" = EXCLUDED.phone_number,
                                "dob" = EXCLUDED.dob, "facebook_exists" = EXCLUDED.facebook_exists, "facebook_year" = EXCLUDED.facebook_year, 
                                "facebook_email" = EXCLUDED.facebook_email, "facebook_phone_number" = EXCLUDED.facebook_phone_number;

INSERT INTO "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"("contact_id", "submission_date", "service", "first_name", "last_name", "street_address",
                                        "street_address_2", "city", "state", "zip", "county", "phone_number", "email", "dob", "facebook_exists", "facebook_year",
                                        "facebook_email", "facebook_phone_number", "submission_id", "investigating_claims", "discovery_package", "discovery_email",
                                        "disney_package", "disney_email", "espn_package", "espn_email", "fubo_package", "fubo_email", "hbo_package", "hbo_email",
                                        "hulu_package", "hulu_email", "mgm_package", "mgm_email", "paramount_package", "paramount_email", "peacock_package",
                                        "peacock_email", "showtime_package", "showtime_email", "sling_package", "sling_email",
                                        "starz_package", "starz_email", "amc_package", "amc_email")
SELECT "contact_id", "submission_date", trim(unnest(string_to_array("services", ';'))), "first_name", "last_name", "street_address",
        "street_address_2", "city", "state", "zip", "county", "phone_number", "email", "dob", "facebook_exists", "facebook_year",
        "facebook_email", "facebook_phone_number", "submission_id", "investigating_claims", "discovery_package", "discovery_email",
        "disney_package", "disney_email", "espn_package", "espn_email", "fubo_package", "fubo_email", "hbo_package", "hbo_email",
        "hulu_package", "hulu_email", "mgm_package", "mgm_email", "paramount_package", "paramount_email", "peacock_package",
        "peacock_email", "showtime_package", "showtime_email", "sling_package", "sling_email",
        "starz_package", "starz_email", "amc_package", "amc_email"
FROM "VPPA_HOLDING";

INSERT INTO "VPPA_AMC"
SELECT "contact_id", "amc_package", "amc_email","submission_date"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'AMC+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_DISCOVERY"
SELECT "contact_id", "discovery_package", "discovery_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Discovery+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_DISNEY"
SELECT "contact_id", "disney_package", "disney_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Disney+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_ESPN"
SELECT "contact_id", "espn_package", "espn_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'ESPN+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_FUBO"
SELECT "contact_id", "fubo_package", "fubo_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Fubo';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_HBO"
SELECT "contact_id", "hbo_package", "hbo_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'HBO MAX';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_HULU"
SELECT "contact_id", "hulu_package", "hulu_email", "submission_date", "email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Hulu';
--ON CONFLICT("primary_email") DO UPDATE SET "package" = EXCLUDED.package, "submission_date" = EXCLUDED.submission_date, "streaming_email" = EXCLUDED.hulu_email;

INSERT INTO "VPPA_MGM"
SELECT "contact_id", "mgm_package", "mgm_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'MGM+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_PARAMOUNT"
SELECT "contact_id", "paramount_package", "paramount_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Paramount+';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_PEACOCK"
SELECT "contact_id", "peacock_package", "peacock_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Peacock';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_SHOWTIME"
SELECT "contact_id", "showtime_package", "showtime_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Showtime Anytime';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_SLING"
SELECT "contact_id", "sling_package", "sling_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Sling';

INSERT INTO "VPPA_STARZ"
SELECT "contact_id", "starz_package", "starz_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Starz';

RETURN NEW;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER new_vppasubmission_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "VPPA_HOLDING"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_vppasubmission_trigger_function();
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_vppasubmission_trigger_function2()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING", "VPPA_HOLDING";

RETURN NEW;
 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER new_vppasubmission_trigger2
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "VPPA_HOLDING"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_vppasubmission_trigger_function2();
```

Tried but getting an error saying it can't truncate because it is being used by active queries in this session.

Comment: Why do you need another `trigger` and not a `stored procedure` that you can call from your (1st) trigger?

Comment: @PM77-1 Haven't looked into stored procedures, but if i create one where would i put the stored procedure so that it automatically executes after the first trigger completes?

Comment: It's up to you when to execute your stored procedure. For example, it can be the last command in your trigger.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628484/sql-differences-between-stored-procedure-and-triggers

Comment: Create just one trigger function/procedure for one trigger. And that single trigger function can use many different functions to do different things, in the right order.

Comment: @PM77-1 Wouldn't that just be the same as putting the truncate statement at the end of the trigger? It gives me the same error about the table being used by active queries in this session.  I believe i need to write the truncate statement/stored procedure somewhere else outside of the initial first trigger

Comment: @FrankHeikens Are you saying to make another trigger that combines these two triggers and they can execute in the right order accordingly without using the same AFTER INSERT condition?  I believe that's my initial problem is that since they are using the same AFTER INSERT condition I was expecting them to execute alphabetically but it still gives me the error that the first trigger is is still going while the second truncate trigger simply just needs to delete the tables that were modified in my first trigger

Comment: @ndomitable Ad *"without using the same AFTER INSERT condition"* - you're not using a [`WHEN` condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#id-1.9.3.93.7) in your trigger definition, there's only the `AFTER INSERT` *event*, same for both. No reason to keep these separate - simply `truncate` right at the end of the first trigger. Or, name them alphabetically: [*If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SUPPORTED-TRIGGER-TYPES)

Comment: No, I'm saying one trigger and one trigger function. And inside this single function, you could use multiple functions (not trigger functions) to do whatever you want. You could also code everything into that single trigger function, but that could result in a lot of code and complexity. Something I try to avoid.

Comment: @Zegarek I'm sorry for being a little slow, can you specify where exactly in the first trigger code I would add the truncate statement?  I've tried adding it multiple places but it's giving me the "cannot TRUNCATE "VPPA_HOLDING" because it is being used by active queries in this session" -- i assumed code works from the top down, and I did place the truncate at the bottom of the code after "INSERT INTO "VPPA_STARZ"
SELECT "contact_id", "starz_package", "starz_email"
FROM "SPLIT_FROM_VPPA_HOLDING"
WHERE "service" = 'Starz';"

Comment: @ndomitable Got it now. You can trade `truncate` for a regular unqualified `delete` - it's slower but not limited in that way: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qva-H2Qo).

Answer (score 1):

There are many aspects of your code that need attention. But the core issue is this:

You cannot `TRUNCATE` a table (`"VPPA_HOLDING"` in your example) in a trigger fired by the same table. That's just impossible and raises the error you observed.

> ERROR:  cannot TRUNCATE "VPPA_HOLDING" because it is being used by active queries in this session

(You should have reported that verbatim error message to begin with. Not in prose, but as exact quote.)

You can replace `TRUNCATE` with an unconditional `DELETE FROM "VPPA_HOLDING"M;` to get rid of the error. That's faster for a small number of rows anyway. (Just make sure the table is vacuumed before to many `DELETE`'s pile up dead tuples.)

- [PostgreSQL delete all content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223820/postgresql-delete-all-content/13226257#13226257)

But the whole approach looks inefficient to begin with. Consider ...

- a single trigger function instead of two.
- a single command with multiple data-modifying CTEs to replace many separate `INSERT` commands
- or (better) a relational model that does not have a separate table for every other company.
- temporary tables as stepping stone instead. Those are much cheaper for volatile data.
- a target column list for all persisted `INSERT` statements.
- a naming policy without this odd mix of lower and upper case identifiers.
- a function or procedure, and no triggers at all.