# Performing a query of a query on stored procedure or recommendation for best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and its purpose is to query a table for rows that do no match the declared `LocID`. However, what I am trying to do now is the best method to filter out my data based on rows that:

1. Do not match the `LocID`
2. Do not match the `ZipCode` from the declared `LocID` value

Code:

```
DECLARE @LocID

SELECT ZipCode
            ,[Description] = ZipCode + ' - ' + Description
FROM LocMap
WHERE LocID <> @LocID
```

Here is a quick layout of table named `LocMap`.

```
LocID | ZipCode | Description
----------------------------------
 100  | 91012   | Magical Sky
 100  | 91013   | Dream Land
 101  | 91012   | Blue Ocean
 102  | 91012   | Gray Screen
 104  | 91014   | Limit Break
 108  | 91016   | Magic Hammer
```

The result is returned in JSON format in order to populate into the second dropdown field on a form based on the `LocID` the user selects from the first dropdown field. So for example, if user selects `LocID = 100` from the first dropdown, then the stored procedure will execute the query and only return `ZipCodes` that are NOT in `LocID = 100`. In this case, the rows with `ZipCodes` 91014 and 91016 would return in the second dropdown.

What would be the best way to perform this? Would this be something I need to do through a subquery in the stored procedure? I feel like I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 2):

There would be a few different ways that you could do this (store ZipCode of LocID you are querying in a variable, CTE, subquery, LEFT OUTER JOIN in query, etc), but in this case, you should really only need to check the second condition (zip <> LocID zip) since that will account for the LocID lookup (the zip of the ID you are checking will knock out that entry).

After that, you should be good with a subquery:

```
DECLARE @LocID INT;

SELECT
    l.[ZipCode],
    [Description] = l.ZipCode + ' - ' + l.Description
FROM LocMap l
WHERE l.ZipCode NOT IN (
    SELECT l2.ZipCode
    FROM LocMap l2
    WHERE l2.LocID = @LocID
);
```

Of course, run [SET STATISTICS IO ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) / check the actual execution plan to make sure that it performs well.  You could go the CTE / join route here as well, but it would likely yield the same query plan, so I would start here.  It really depends on the situation as to [which is a better fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: This looks like the optimal query to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated sub-query. Note, you don't have to explicitly exclude `@LocID` as it will get excluded by the second criteria too.

```
select
    ZipCode,
    [Description] = ZipCode + ' - ' + Description
from
    LocMap l1
where
    Not Exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            LocMap l2
        where
            l2.LocID = @LocID and
            l2.ZipCode = l1.ZipCode
    );
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68e68/3)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "over thinking", you don't need a stored procedure - you just need a query. IMHO, [stored procedures are to be avoided wherever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369030/256196).

This query will do it:

```
select
  a.ZipCode,
  a.ZipCode + '-' + a.Description as Description
from LocMap a
left join LocMap b on b.locid = 100
  and a.ZipCode = b.ZipCode
where a.locid != 100
and b.ZipCode is null
```

This works by looking for missed joins on a matched ZipCode when joined to itself and should significantly outperform a non-join approach.