# Correct way of constructing and executing SQL statements for React app with Postgres db?

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql, rest

I have a React app that uses node js on backend. I use PostgreSQL as my db. I have written several APIs that do various inserts, deletes, or updates. Some of these inserts have proven to be somewhat more complicated in that I may be inserting a large variable amount of records to a table at once. Therefore, I have created separate functions designed to construct these statements. These methods live on the client side and usually loop through some list and create a string that represents the SQL statement to be executed. Then, one of the APIs is called, and it passes this string to it to be executed.

However, I am wondering if this is actually best practice, or if there are reasons to why this is frowned upon, unnecessary, or there's just a plain better way of doing this.

**These are some options I have thought of:**

1. Doing the same procedure described, but moving the code to construct the statements to the server side (Though I think this is the worst option of the 3, since it involves more server side code).
2. Using prepared statements, though I couldn't find a clean way of doing this since my SQL statements have a variable amount of records to be inserted and prepared statements typically expect an explicit number of parameters (correct me if this is wrong).
3. Stick with what I am doing now (build a String with the SQL statement in it on the client side and call the api passing the string and then executing). I really feel like this is not best practice though for some reason.

Please let me know if any of these options make sense and what I am missing.

Also: I thought I would create an example scenario of what my application does currently to make things clearer.

**User:**
creates a list of "objects". They may add as many "objects" to the list as they want.

**User:**
will hit "submit"

**Client code:**
Will loop through, appending "objects" to a String called "sql_query" which looks something like the following -> "INSERT INTO lists(num, char) VALUES (1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C").

**Client code:**
Calls api: axios.post(api/createlist, {sql_query});

**Api:**
verifies cookies, executes sql command, error handling.

Comment: [Be very careful when deciding to use stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369030/256196). Prepared statements, possibly dynamically created if necessary, are best practice.

Comment: For security reasons you should avoid SQL queries on your frontend.

    
The reason for that is because if I had malicious intentions I could easily delete your database, or steal all your data you have on your SQL server by injecting my own custom SQL queries, which will be executed by your node.js app without validation.


To avoid that you need to send only your data to your node.js app, then let node.js create the SQL query to update the data. You can skip writing your own SQL queries and use an ORM like sequelize to do the heavy lifting for you.